# How can I set selectively set the foreground color of a text in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtextedit

So, I have a `QtGui.QTextEdit` that I want to append with text based on some condition. For eg:

```
resultbox = QtGui.QTextEdit()
text = 'example'
if condition1:
    resultbox.append(text) '''Append text to resultbox in default color.'''
elif condition2:
    resultbox.append(text) '''Append the text in say, red and not the default black. How?'''
```

I am looking for something like a `setForegroundColor(QtColor)` method on `QString(text)` that will allow me to set the foreground color for the text.

I tried to work with stylehseets in PyQt4 by setting a color for the `QTextEdit`, but that won't allow me to selectively color the text, right?

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTextEdit` can handle regular html content, so you could use the following to achieve your desire:

```
resultbox = QtGui.QTextEdit()
text = 'example'
if condition1:
    resultbox.insertText(text) '''Append text to resultbox in default color.'''
elif condition2:
    resultbox.insertHtml(QString("<font color=\"red\">%1</font>").arg(text)) '''Append the text in say, red and not the default black. How?'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `QTextEdit.textCursor` to get the cursor, then use `QTextCursor.setCharFormat` to set format.

```
resultbox = QtGui.QTextEdit()
text = 'example'
if condition1:
    resultbox.append(text) '''Append text to resultbox in default color.'''
elif condition2:
    resultbox.textCursor().setCharFormat(specialFormat)
    resultbox.append(text) '''Append the text in say, red and not the default black. How?'''
    resultbox.textCursor().setCharFormat(defaultFormat)
```

Or you can use `QTextEdit.insertHtml` to insert some HTML code into text, which you can specify the color by `style` attribute.

Comment: Why not just use HTML?

Comment: @rainer You are right. `QTextEdit.setHtml` is an easier way to do it.